# Java Most efficient way of creating Button actionListener?

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, jbutton, edt

I am working on a project that involves GUI. On the JFrame I have several JButtons that perform specific actions when clicked. Now the problem is, with the code I wrote, every time the buttons are clicked, they generate a new thread. I do this because I learned that JFrame would freeze if everything happens on the same thread, but I feel that creating that many threads isn't very efficient. Although the program functions pretty well for now, I still hope to cut off redundant pieces from the program. Should put all the GUI things in an "InvokeLater"? But aren't jButtons also in the GUI? Some actions the these Button perform required an existing GUI, so it's hard to separate them...  Any ideas? Here is an example of the button.

```
JButton buttonA4= new JButton("Deact Crew");
buttonA4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() {
                    DinnerList.deactivateGroup(tempJobCrew.getCrews());
                    studentTable.repaint();
                    }
                });         
                hilo.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: As you write you currently face no problem, do you?

Your concern is that one new thread per button click will tear down your system? How fast can your user click?

Comment: *"but I feel that creating that many threads isn't very efficient"* - They're relatively short lived, so I wouldn't worry about - just remember, Swing is NOT thread safe, so you shouldn't be modifying the UI or anything the UI relies on from out side the context of the EDT

Comment: *"I still hope to cut off redundant pieces from the program"* - I would recommend that you have a look at [How to use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) which provides a concept of self contained, reusable approach to handling common actions

Comment: I think it is better to use "Executor" class for handling threads ... creating a thread pool makes sense if you are sure you're going to use threads.

Comment: *"Should put all the GUI things in an "InvokeLater"?"* - `invokeLater` will ensure that the `Runnable` is executing on the EDT, so more context would be required into what you wanted to "run later" before we could make an assessment. *"But aren't jButtons also in the GUI? Some actions the these Button perform required an existing GUI, so it's hard to separate them"* - I would strongly suggest you focus on separating your UI from your data and the actions that modify it, this is the bases of the Model View Controller paradigm

Comment: I would also strongly suggest having a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which provides a means for working with "background tasks" and managing the UI

Comment: @MadProgrammer So basically, I should put the whole createUI method in the invokeLater and delete all "thread" and runnable in the actionPerformed?

Comment: @Ptolemorphism Based on the context I have at hand, I can't answer that question - but, you should only every modify the UI from within the context of the EDT. Maybe you need to use a `SwingWorker` to prepare the data, which would allow you to then create the UI after the worker has completed

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I don't have a very long task, is it ok to jam all the "actionPerformed" in the EDT?

Comment: @Ptolemorphism If it doesn't degrade the user experience. Users would prefer a wait indicator for a second or two, rather then an app which does nothing

Comment: @MadProgrammer For now the only user of the program is myself, so I guess its fine. But I will definitely look into the topics you mentioned! Just a quick another question: how do you insert JLabels at the start of a new line in JTextPane? Now it just adds the label to the end of the previous one. Thank you!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I looked into SwingWorkers and it seems that it cannot be reused and only 10 of them can be instantiated? I definitely need to perform tasks more than 10 times. What should I do?

Comment: @Ptolemorphism You can create as many instances as you like, as often as you like, how ever, SwingWorker will only allow 10 to run simultaneously